# Regex to search two string inside a method

Tags: regex

How to create a regex , so as to search two strings "greet" AND inside this method string "name" .
I tried

```
(^.*greet(\n|.|\t)*)(.*name*)
```

```
def greet(name):
    print("Hello, " + name + ". Good morning!") <--- this name should be selected 

def meet(name):
    print("Lets meet, " + name )
```

Comment: `(` and `)` have special meaning in regex, you must escape them like so if you wish for them to be literal: `\(` and `\)`

Answer (score 0):

I would use this regex:

```
greet([^\n]|\n+[^\S\n])*name
```

Here the strings `greet` and `name` are separated by characters that are not a linebreak (`[^\n]`) or, in the case, they must be eventually followed by a space that is not a linebreak (`[^\S\n]`). In this way you ensure that name is in the same method of greet.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/p3XNHA/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can capture in a group what is between the parenthesis, and use a backreference `\1` in the next line to match the same.

If you want to select it, you could also capture that in a group itself.

```
\bdef greet\(([^\s()]+)\):\r?\n.*(\1)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FZUe56/1)

If it should be `name` only

```
 \bdef greet\([^\s()]+\):\r?\n.*\b(name)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BtrtpN/1)